# Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get this effect in my UI:  https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout.

1) I added to my build.gradle the compile '...' for this library

2) I created  `workout_main.xml` file ( I'll post the code below)

3) I use a fragment which extends a base fragment class ( which is created by my activity). I'm able to use inflate view for other fragment in this activity but this one seems to crash because of the library I'm using. I'm not sure if that would be the culprit or the way I'm approaching things

As an aside, I looked on their GitHub open / closed issues and the only "solutions" to this problem was using `android.enableAapt2=false` in the  `gradle.properties` file. ( which didn't work)

WORKOUT_MAIN.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:expandable="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.andexert.expandablelayout.library"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/workout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.liberty.android.fantastischmemo.ui.AnyMemo">


    <com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        expandable:el_headerLayout="@layout/view_header"
        expandable:el_contentLayout="@layout/view_content"
        android:background="#e74c3c"/>

    <com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayoutListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_below="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

2)Fragment where it's called

```
public class WorkoutTabFragment extends BaseFragment {

    private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    private final AtomicInteger workoutListVersion = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final static String TAG = WorkoutTabFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private WorkoutListAdapter woAdapter;

    @Inject WorkOutListUtil workoutList;

    @Inject DatabaseUtil databaseUtil;

    @Inject RecentListActionModeUtil recentListActionModeUtil;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fragmentComponents().inject(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.open_screen_menu, menu);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //ERRROR HAPPENS HERE
        View v = inflater.inflate( R.layout.workout_main, container, false);
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        /* pre loading stat */
        woAdapter = new WorkoutListAdapter(getContext(), workoutList, recentListActionModeUtil);
         final String[] array = {"Hello", "World", "Android", "is", "Awesome", "World", "Android", "is", "Awesome", "World", "Android", "is", "Awesome", "World", "Android", "is", "Awesome"};

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.view_row, R.id.header_text, array);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        return v;
    }
```

3) My LOGCAT

```
-18 11:43:53.672 5331-5331/org.liberty.android.fantastischmemodev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: org.liberty.android.fantastischmemodev, PID: 5331
  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
      at org.liberty.android.fantastischmemo.ui.WorkoutTabFragment.onCreateView(WorkoutTabFragment.java:126)
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2248)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1340)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1569)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1636)
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2201)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2155)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2034)
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:668)
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:630)
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:611)
      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2191)
      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1164)
      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1157)
      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1127)
      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1426)
      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1536)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HeaderLayout and ContentLayout cannot be null!
      at com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout.init(ExpandableLayout.java:71)
      at com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout.<init>(ExpandableLayout.java:52)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
      at org.liberty.android.fantastischmemo.ui.WorkoutTabFragment.onCreateView(WorkoutTabFragment.java:126) 
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2248) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1340) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1569) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1636) 
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2201) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2155) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2034) 
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143) 
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268) 
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:668) 
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:630) 
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:611) 
      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2191) 
      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1164) 
      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1157) 
      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1127) 
      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1426) 
      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1536) 
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Remove the `expandable` namespace definition in your layout, and use the `app` prefix on those attributes; e.g., `app:el_headerLayout=...`.

Comment: That is actually throwing off all kind of errors when building. (such as 'No resource identifier found for attribute 'el_headerLayout' in package') I thought I'd have to add the expandable namespace because it's part of the library.

Comment: Ah, I changed it to whatever choice was given by android studio ( so app:headerLayout) but it's still crashing.

Comment: Yeah, that's going to resolve 'cause `headerLayout` is defined in the support libraries, but that's not the attribute `ExpandableLayout` is looking for. `contentLayout` shouldn't resolve at all. Which version of that library are you using? The author changed those attributes to add the `el_` prefix a coupla versions ago, it looks like. 1.3 is the latest, even though the README shows 1.2.2 in the examples. Make sure 1.3 is the version you're using, the attributes are `el_headerLayout` and `el_contentLayout`, and you're using the `app` prefix on them. Then rebuild. I just tested it myself.

Comment: So, I did a clean build and the options showed ( el_headerLayout and such). However, I'm still getting an inflater error whenever I try to inflate the workout_main.xml file. This is really throwing me off... Also, I just updated it and currently I'm using 1.3.

Comment: If inflation is still failing, it should be something different now. Check the stack trace again.

Comment: it worked. Thank you, I'd give you more upvotes if I could.